# Como hacer un script en python para filtrar malas palabras?

Tags: python, script, filtro

Encontré un filtro parecido a lo que necesito hacer pero en PHP, no encuentro ningún  ejemplo que pueda seguir hecho en python, alguien que me pueda ayudar?

```
<?php 


//Lista de palabras censuradas 
$censuradas=array('mamón', 'mendrugo', 'zopenco');
//Contamos la partes
$partes=count($censuradas);

//Texto para filtrar
$frasecompleta='Tengo un amigo que es muy mamón y la vez su primo es un mendrugo bastante zopenco. ';

//Recorremos la cadena para censurar las palabras prohibidas
for ($i=0; $i < $partes; $i++) { 
    if( strpos($frasecompleta,$censuradas[$i]) !== false ){
        //Replazamos las prohibidas con ****
        $frasecompleta=str_replace($censuradas[$i],'****',$frasecompleta);
    }
}

//Frase limpia de palabras prohibidas
echo $frasecompleta;


?>
```

Comment: `for palabra in censuradas:
    frasecompleta = frasecompleta.replace(palabra, "***")`

Comment: No busques, a veces, buscando no hayas la respuesta. En su lugar, intentalo. Ademas, no respondemos preguntas donde el autor no demuestra esfuerzo por responderlas.

Comment: El comentario de @CandidMoe fallaria en frases como "quiero usar la computadora", la cual cambia a "quiero usar la com***dora". Sin embargo, hace lo mismo (aparentemente) que el script original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando expresiones regulares puedes montar una que use `|` para especificar como alternativas las palabras de la lista de censuradas, y puedes usar `re.sub()` para reemplazarlas por otra cadena, todas a la vez, sin necesidad de iterar.

Además, usando `\b` (que indica límite de palabra) en la expresión regular puedes indicar que el reemplazo sólo ocurra cuando el matching se dé en palabras completas, y no con subcadenas dentro de una palabra, para evitar cosas como que "computadora" sea convertida a "com***dora" como indicaba @Dante.S en un comentario.

El código sería este:

```py
import re
frasecompleta='Mi amigo es muy mamón, y la vez su primo, al que llaman mamónides, es un mendrugo bastante zopenco.'

censuradas=['mamón', 'mendrugo', 'zopenco']
regex = "|".join(censuradas)
frasecompleta = re.sub(f"\\b({regex})\\b", "***", frasecompleta)
print(frasecompleta)
```

Resultado:

```
Mi amigo es muy ***, y la vez su primo, al que llaman mamónides, es un *** bastante ***.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
frasecompleta = str(input('Comentario: '))
"Mi vecino bobo"

import re

def filtro(frasecompleta):
        censuradas= ['mamón', 'bobo', 'pendejo', 'idiota']
        regex = "|".join(censuradas)
        frasecompleta = re.sub(f"\\b({regex})\\b", "CENSURADO", frasecompleta)
        if 'CENSURADO' in frasecompleta:
            return('Comentario Censurado')
        else:
            return('El comentario cumple las normas')

filtro(frasecompleta)
'Comentario Censurado'
```

Al final así quedó el código, muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple). No agregues otra respuesta complementaria a la aceptada...